# key error: 'x' --> adding key value pair in for loop, key being char

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I am a beginner in python and I am trying to solve a coding problem, got this error. Don't understand why ? I went through a couple of Q/A's here but they don't seem to solve my problem. Essentially what I am trying to do is iterate over a string, through its characters and fill these characters in a dictionary. With characters being the keys and values being the number of times these characters appeared. So I'm trying the following:

```
 def myfunc(mystring):
 for i in mystring:
    if charCounter[i]:
       charCounter[i] += 1
    charCounter[i] = 1

 mystring = "hello! how are you ?"
 myfunc(mystring)
```

and Im getting following error:

> File "xyq.py", line 3, in myfunc
>       if CharCounter[i]:
>   KeyError: 'h'

Can someone please suggest, where am I going wrong ? And if possible how can I improve the code ?

Thanks

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. What is `charCounter`? Where is it initialised?

Comment: Sorry! Somehow I missed it in my code. charCounter is a dictionary
charCounter = {} and this is declared inside myfunc at the top.

Comment: @CodeInfinity You can re-edit your question. Please do so to improve the quality of your question for future readers. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if `i` is in `charCounter` before you try to retrieve it:

```
if i in charCounter:
    charCounter[i] += 1
else:
    charCounter[i] = 1
```

Or alternatively:

```
if charCounter.get(i):
   ...
```

Comment: Hi Zach! 
Thanks for your suggestion. charCounter is actually an empty dictionary here declared inside myfunc. Somehow I missed to write it here.  What can be done in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

```
if charCounter[i]:
```

throws `KeyError` if the key does not exist. What you want to do isuse `if i in charCounter:` instead:

```
if i in char_counter:
    char_counter[i] += 1
else:
    char_counter[i] = 1
```

Alternatively you could use `get` which *gets* the value if it exists, or returns the second (optional) value if it didn't exist:

```
char_counter[i] = char_counter.get(i, 0) + 1
```

However this counting pattern is so popular that a whole class exists for it: [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def my_func(my_string):
    return Counter(my_string)
```

Example:

```
>>> counts = my_func('hello! how are you ?')
>>> counts
Counter({' ': 4, 'o': 3, 'h': 2, 'l': 2, 'e': 2, '!': 1, 'r': 1, 'a': 1,
         '?': 1, 'w': 1, 'u': 1, 'y': 1})
>>> counts[' ']
4
```

`collections.Counter` is a subclass of dictionary, so it would behave in the same way that an ordinary dictionary would do with item access and so forth.

Comment: Hi! 
Thanks for your suggestion. charCounter is actually an empty dictionary here declared inside myfunc. Somehow I missed to write it here. What can be done in that case ?

Comment: @CodeInfinity fixed

Comment: Thanks @Antii, i'll try this out